# Prevent automatically create more on ios tabbar

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I use https://github.com/itsKaynine/SwiftRaisedTab for center rasedbutton.

I test with storyboard, but something strange.

[image: First View]

this is my app's view

[image: Select Tab]

click third tab

[image: Click Title Cell]

segue linked with show, and I clicked cancel for exit

[image: After click cancel]

tab bar is changed. why appears more button?

[image: Storyboard]

this is my storyboard

I want just back and forth tab to detail
I don't want more button. tab bar buttons should be fixed 4 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *https://github.com/itsKaynine/SwiftRaisedTab* 's errors

everytime called `insertEmptyItem` and `addRaisedButton`.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftRaisedTab

class ViewController: RaisedTabBarController {
    var isActivated: Bool = false
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if(!isActivated) {
            isActivated = true
            // Insert empty tab item at center index. In this case we have 5 tabs.
            self.insertEmptyTabItem("", atIndex: 2)

            // Raise the center button with image
            let img = UIImage(named: "icon_camera")
            self.addRaisedButton(img, highlightImage: nil)
        }
    }

    // Handler for raised button
    override func onRaisedButton(sender: UIButton!) {
        super.onRaisedButton(sender)

        println("Raised button tapped")
    }

}
```